# Tube amplifier preamplifier

Tags: vacuum-tube, preamp

I received this little two tube preamp
http://www.gikfun.com/electronic-diy-kits-c-7/6j1-tube-preamplifier-board-20-stereo-multiple-diy-kit-p-730.html

It comes with 9 470uF caps. The symbol on the board for them is a circle, with white strips across one of the legs. Does anyone know if that indicates the positive leg of the capacitor?

Also, I don't read Chinese characters. Which set of RCA plugs are the input?
No word back from GikFun to these questions yet.

There is no schematic posted to work out the details myself.

Thanks

Updated - added a picture of the labels[image]

Updated - added a picture showing two of capacitor pins that both connect to the RCA plugs common plane -[image] and to the common pins of the AC input jack.

Ah ha! Found an e-bay listing that confirms  Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy's answer.  Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Establish if most of them share the same ground terminal (maybe a large copper plane).

Comment: Tubes? I can barely remember those obsolete old things. Why use them today?

Comment: My earliest impression with great tube designs in 60's were super low noise and crisp wide bandwidth  with lots of kick

Comment: Just a general comment those Chinese 6j1 amplifiers are kind of a waste of time.... They misuse the tube and aren't really good at doing much of anything. Read a book and make a simple tube amplifier out of audio tubes and a real output transformer... It'll sound way better than whatever that thing does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google says
Input + Output
输入 + 输出

Stripe is -VE

Comment: Thank you, will try to confirm if any negatives connect to what appear to be the RCA plug negatives as a check.  Going to need a  magnifying class to read the symbols!

Comment: 别客气。 我也不懂中文。
Bié kèqì. Wǒ yě bù dǒng zhōngwén.

Comment: Then a photo then Zoom it

Comment: Ok, so the terminals near the screw would appear to be the Inputs.